# error while creating a new administrator in Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04

While creating a new admin user in Ubuntu, it is throwing an error:

```
running '/usr/sbin/adduser' failed: Child process exited with code 1
```

Please help me to create a another admin user in Ubuntu. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 version.

Comment: You can add the user to sudo group using the cmd  "adduser <username> sudo".So user will have all administrative privileges.

Comment: Maybe you are entering username in caps. Try entering it in small letters.

Comment: Are you running `adduser` with `sudo`? Regular users can't run `adduser`.

Answer (score 1):

What was the username you tried to add?

I believe, given the information you've provided, the username entered is at fault.

Example:

> **Valid Ussernames**:
>
> - normanli
> - norman.li
>
> **Invalid Usernames**:
>
> - Norman Li
> - bob dole
> - Norman.Li

See Valid Username [Rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6949667/what-are-the-real-rules-for-linux-usernames-on-centos-6-and-rhel-6)

and an Ubuntu Forum [Post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2228724) similar to yours.

Comment: tried with 'sampleuser' is the user name

Answer (score 1):

To add a new user you should type:

```
sudo adduser <username>
```

to add sudo rights to the user:

```
sudo adduser <username> sudo
```

and you should replace (obviously)  with the username desired by you, in the format as Norman Li pointed out...

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu the admin user is the users which has access to root throught sudo. So, you've to create a normal user and put his login in the sudoer list with the visudo tool in the terminal. So the command should be:

```
sudo visudo
```

Consult `man visudo` first, if you want to give the root access your new login to one or several application

Comment: you mean to say i cannot create two admin users in ubuntu using system setting -> user accounts ? Am I correct ? I tried to create standard user also but it is throwing same error.

Comment: I mean you've to add it in sudo access. So system setting should be launched with sudo or gksudo if you're in GUI mode.

Comment: i tried with sudo adduser username also through terminal. but it is also not allowing to add th euser